# Auto width images in columns using pdfmake.js

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

I'm trying to create a simple 2-up image layout, so each image is 50% page width in two columns, however the 'auto' or '*' widths don't seem to work with images.

Is there any way to achieve this without setting explicit widths for the images?

Or if not, is it possible to get the width of the page so I can do the math myself?

**Edit:**

A simplified version of the code I've tried is:

```
var dd = {
content: [
    {
        columns: [
            {
                image: 'sampleImage.jpg',
                width: 'auto'
            },
            {
                image: 'sampleImage.jpg',
                width: '*'
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Using those auto widths I just get `Uncaught Error: unsupported number: NaN` in the console. If I change them to fixed widths, however, they work fine.

Comment: post your code, what did you try?

Comment: Updated question @NikhilRadadiya

Comment: I think you have to use fixed width, as you can see in playground example  http://pdfmake.org/playground.html

Comment: Yeah that's the point, I either need percentage based/auto widths, or I need a way to know how big the page is (in pixels) that I'm printing out so I can work out a fixed width myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this functionality is available in the library or not. People have raised this as an issue on the pdfmake github issue page, and the same are still open.

- [Set image size in percentage of the page](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/862)
- [Image auto widths and columns](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/1109)

But you can still implement it yourself by taking page width.

```
var pageWidth = 900;
var pageHeigth = 1000;

var docDefinition = {
    pageSize: {
        width: pageWidth,
        height: pageHeigth
    },
    pageMargins: [10, 10, 10, 10],
    content: [{
        image: imageEncodedData,
        width: pageWidth / 2, // for 50 % image width
        height: pageHeigth / 2, // change the numbers accordingly
        absolutePosition: {  // absolute positioning if required
            x: 270,
            y: 45
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: How are you getting that page width size? Or is it just a random number?

Comment: Although it's a random number, but you can always use logic with screen.width and screen.height property of javascript for more dynamic values (if you are making use on the browser side).

Comment: There's also support for standard page sizes like A4, A5 pages, whole list available at last section of http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted

Comment: screen.width doesn't equate to the printable area on the paper. I have gone for a4 paper at 72dpi to get pixel values (595 * 842) but thought there might be a better way. Cheers.